# How to do cleaning up on exit in Qt

Tags: qt

I'd like to do some house keeping stuff (like writing to a file etc) in a Qt app before the app exits. How can I get to this function (exit or whatever is called) in Qt?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to connect a slot with the clean up code to the `QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit()` signal.

This allows you to delete QObjects with `QObject::deleteLater()` and the objects will be deleted as you have not yet left the main application event loop.

If you are using a C library that requires a 'shutdown' call you can normally do that after the return from `QCoreApplication::exec()`.

Example for both techniques:

```
int main(int,char**)
{
  QApplication app;
  library_init();
  QWidget window;
  window.show();
  QObject::connect(&app, SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()), &window, SLOT(closing()));
  const int retval = app.exec();
  library_close();
  return retval;
}
```

Comment: Note that current Qt documentation specifically recommends against doing anything after exec returns. See (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#exec)

Comment: Note that a reboot from terminal or a lost X connection triggers a ::exit() which does not emit aboutToQuit. (at least until 5.7)

Answer (score 11):

In regards to Silas Parker's answer, the Qt documentation says this about the `aboutToQuit` signal:

> The signal is particularly useful if your application has to do some
>   last-second cleanup. Note that no user interaction is possible in this
>   state.

If you want your application to be able to cancel the exiting process or allow the user to perform a last minute change before the application closes, then you can do this by handling the `closeEvent` function in your `MainWindow`.

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    if (maybeSave()) {
        writeSettings();
        event->accept();
    } else {
        event->ignore();
    }
}
```

See the [closeEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#closeEvent) documentation for more information.

Comment: How can this be handled in QApplication instead of QMainWIndow?

Comment: @pra16 `QApplication` doesn't really have a corollary to `closeEvent`. You could try using [`lastWindowClosed`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#lastWindowClosed) or use signal handling to interrupt the suspend/close signals.